# Copy Big Buffer into chunks of smaller buffer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a huge buffer of known size. I need to copy chunks of it to send via sockets to a server. For this purspose I am trying to copy say 1024 bytes at a time and then send it.

The catch here is, I do not know the contents of the buffer. It could be strings or binary. It should work with all data contained in the buffer.

Here is the code that I have written and that doesnt work of course. It is just a small test code and I use a string first.Later I want to test it with some binary etc. But firstly I have to gt the pointer concepts right!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char hexstr [] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
    //trying with a string
    char Bbuf [20]= "Hihelloohowareyou?";
    FillBuffer( Bbuf,sizeof(Bbuf));

        return 0;
}


int FillBuffer(char *bigbuf, int len){

    char smallbuf[4];
    int i = 0;
    int buflen= sizeof(smallbuf);
    printf("length of smallbuf is= %d\n",buflen);
    printf("length of original string= %d\n", len);
    for( i=buflen; i< len+buflen;i =i+buflen){
        memcpy(smallbuf,bigbuf,i);
        printf("i== %d\n", i);
        bigbuf= bigbuf+i;
        //printf("smallbuf conatins= %s\n", smallbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im not sure what you are doing there, but I guess you are trying to do something like:

```
void Stuff(char* bbuf, int size)
{
    char buf[4];
    int remain = size;
    while (remain)
    {
      int toCpy = remain > sizeof(buf) ? sizeof(buf) : remain;
      memcpy(buf, bbuf, toCpy);
      bbuf += toCpy;
      remain -= toCpy;
      DoStuff(&buf, toCpy); //Send the buffer or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *essentially* right. The only part that wouldn't work is the `printf`, because if you have binary content, you can't show it in the console.

Also, note that when sending to sockets, that are non-ending sinks, you have to specify the length of what you're sending, for the other end to know how many bytes to read.

Comment: how can copying a buffer of size 20 into a buffer of size 4 be correct?

Comment: It is inside a loop, it is copying chunks of size 4 till the bigger buffer goes empty. Actually, the code is not OK, but it is a matter of indices and lengths, the idea is OK.

Comment: @user489152, you can see an example of how to do the loop correctly in @Robert J. answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i += buflen)
{
    memcpy(smallbuf,bigbuf+i,buflen);
    printf("i== %d\n", i);
    // Note that printf wont work since the string is not NULL-terminated.
    //printf("smallbuf conatins= %s\n", smallbuf);
}
```

If you want to send this over network, you would probably want to put you buffer into a packet struct with at least information on how much of the data is actually useful (if the big buffer size is not divisible by the small one). If you want to send other data than strings, you can't really use NULL-termination for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy anything, as both sendto and write take a size argument. If you have 20 bytes of data in the buffer B, and you want to break it into two packets of size 10 on the socket, you just do:

```
write( sock, B, 10 );
write( sock, B + 10, 10 );
```

(or s/write/sendto/ and add a flags argument).

Using memcpy is just wasting time in this situation.